# Reference another class in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm just starting out with Python for Google App Engine. I have a file notifications.py, and in here, I will be creating User entities, which are specified in users.py. How can I do this? I've tried `import users`, but I get an error: `NameError: global name 'User' is not defined`

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I just had this problem too! After you do:

```
import users
```

to get `User` you have to type `users.User`

Alternatively you could import it like:

```
from users import User
```

then reference it as just `User` but if you do it this way you'll have to list every bit from users that you want in the following format:

```
from users import User, Somthingelse, Somthing
```

If you're feeling super lazy and you don't want to type in any prefixes or list all the things you want, just type

```
from users import *
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
import users
```

do

```
from users import User
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# module.py
foo = "bar"
# main.py
import module
print foo # This will cause error because foo is not located in the current namespace
print module.foo # this will print "bar"
from module import foo # But you can import contents of module "module" in the current namespace
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html